# How; The most difficult question of your life

Tags: javascript

```js
function factorial2(n) {
  for (product = 1; n > product; product++) {
    product *= n;
  }

  return product;
}
factorial2(4);
```

return is receiving 5, why?

factorial2(4);

Comment: Ok, I assume the code is broken but it should stop at the first iteration

Comment: What input are you giving the function?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the function through with a debugger? Or adding `console.log` statements?

Comment: ...you're using the same variable as a loop counter *and* you modify it in the body. That is bound to give you "weird" results. Well, results that are exactly correct but very likely you don't want.

Comment: Declare `product` outside of the loop, since you are using it to return. Also, don't return a loop step variable, unless it is happening inside the loop...

Comment: When selecting a question title choose one that summarizes the question. Question titles should not be intriguing mystery boxes.

Comment: factorial2(4), sorry

Comment: @VLAZ, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns 5 on first iteration if you pass 4 to it. In general it returns `n + 1` *for any n > 1*.

Following the code path, it can be unrolled into

```
product = 1
n > product // true, loop
product *= n // so product is n
product++ // end of loop, product is n+1
n > product // false, exit loop

return product
```

If `n === 1`, the first check is false so it returns just 1.

Comment: Just to specify - for positive `n > 1`. For `n <= 1` it's `1`

Comment: Thank you, amended

Answer (score 0):

If you want an iterative factorial function, you want to separate your step (`step`) variable and your accumulator (`product`).

```js
function factorialIterative(n) {
  let product = 1;
  for (let step = 1; step <= n; step++) {
    product *= step;
  }
  return product;
}

new Array(10).fill(0).forEach((v, i) =>
  console.log(`${i} => ${factorialIterative(i)}`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```